# $y'' + y' -2y = x^2$, find $A, B$, & and $C$ such that $y = Ax^2+Bx+C$ satisfies this equation.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I am doing an extra credit problem for college. I don't expect anyone to solve it for me, but I would really appreciate being given some hints.

**The problem:**

> $y'' + y' -2y = x^2$, find $A, B$, & and $C$ such that the function $y = Ax^2+Bx+C$ satisfies this equation.

I understand how to find derivatives if I know the function, but this is stumping me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that $y = y(x)$ is of the given form, we need only substitute $y$ into the differential equation 
$$
y^{\prime\prime} + y^\prime  - 2y = x^2
$$
and solve for $A,B$ and $C$. Now, we have
\begin{align}\label{eq:1}\tag{1}
y^\prime(x) = 2Ax + B \quad \text{and} \quad y^{\prime\prime}(x) = 2A.
\end{align}
So, if $y$ solves the differential equation, then
\begin{align}
x^2 = y^{\prime\prime} + y^\prime  - 2y &= 2A + (2Ax+B) -2\left(Ax^2 + Bx + C \right)\label{eq:2}\tag{2}\\
&= -2Ax^2 + (2A-2B)x + \left( 2A + B -2C\right)\label{eq:3}\tag{3}.
\end{align}
Comparing the coefficients of this equation, we find that
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
-2A = 1,\\
2A-2B = 0,\\
2A+B-2C = 0.
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
Solving this system will give the explicit values of $A,B$ and $C$ required.

Comment: What do you replace $y^{\prime\prime} + y^\prime  - 2y = x^2$ with, when you solve for $A, B$, and $C$?

Comment: I substitute in the expressions for $y,y^\prime$ and $y^{\prime\prime}$ in terms of $x$, respectively.

Comment: Oh, so you do $y''(x) + y'(x) - 2y(x) = x^2$ then get rid of $x^2$ and solve for $y'(x)$ and $y''(x)$ respectively?

Comment: Not exactly. I'm not getting rid of anything, I am only comparing coefficients. If two polynomials are everywhere equal, then their coefficients must agree. Using this, I'm solving for $A,B$ and $C$.

Comment: So when you say you're substituting in the expressions for $y$, $y'$ and $y''$ in terms of x, you're replacing them with A, B, and C and then simplifying?

Comment: I'm not replacing anything with $A,B$ and $C$. Plugging the expressions from (1) into our differential equation, I obtain the identity in (2) which I then clean up to get (3).

Comment: Now, (3) says that $x^2 = -2Ax^2 + (2A-2B)x + \left( 2A + B -2C\right)$. The coefficients of the second order terms must then be equal, so thus $1 = -2A$. Similarly, the coefficients of the first order terms are equal. This implies that $2A-2B = 0$ ($x^2$ has no first order terms). Then, we do the same for zero order terms.

Comment: I am not understanding how you get step 1 in the first place though.

Comment: You want solutions of the form $y(x) = Ax^2 + Bx + C$. Any solution of this form will have to satisfy (1) by the power-rule.

Comment: But how do you know what $y'(x)$ and $y''(x)$ equal?

Comment: What happens if you differentiate $y(x) = Ax^2 + Bx + C$?

Comment: ohh! I get it! thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you plug the quadratic polynomial into your differential equation you will get

$$2A+(2Ax+B)-2(Ax^2+Bx+C)=x^2.$$

Compare the coefficients and determine $A$, $B$, $C$.

Answer (score 1):

With

$y = Ax^2 + Bx + C, \tag 1$

we may substitute $y$, $y'$, and $y''$ into

$y'' + y' - 2y = x^2, \tag 2$

***viz,***

$y' = 2Ax + B, \tag 3$

$y'' = 2A, \tag 4$

$y'' + y' - 2y = 2A + (2Ax + B) - 2(Ax^2 + Bx + C) = x^2; \tag 5$

we group together like powers of $x$:

$-2Ax^2 + 2(A - B) x + (2A + B -2C) = x^2, \tag 5$

from which we infer

$-2A = 1, \tag 6$

$2(A - B) = 0, \tag 7$

$2A + B - 2C = 0; \tag 8$

thus

$A = B = -\dfrac{1}{2}, \tag 9$

$C = -\dfrac{3}{4}, \tag{10}$

and of course

$y = -\dfrac{1}{2}x^2 - \dfrac{1}{2}x - \dfrac{3}{4}. \tag{11}$

***We Check:***

From (11),

$y' = -x - \dfrac{1}{2}, \tag{12}$

$y'' = -1, \tag{13}$

$y'' + y' - 2y$
$= -1 - x - \dfrac{1}{2} - 2(-\dfrac{1}{2}x^2 - \dfrac{1}{2}x - \dfrac{3}{4}) = -1 - x - \dfrac{1}{2} + x^2 + x + \dfrac{3}{2} = x^2. \tag{14}$

Comment: How did you  do steps 6, 7, and 8?

Comment: @LuminousNutria:  I simply took (5) and equated the coefficients of powers of $x$--$x^0 = 1, \; x^1, \; x^2$--occurring on each side.

Comment: So, $-2A=1$ because the coefficient of $x^2$ is 1? And $2(A - B) = 0$ because the coefficients of $2x - 2x$ equal $1 - 1$ and are therefore zero? And $(2A+B-2C) = 0$ because it has no powers of x?

Comment: @LuminousNutria:  yes!  Basically what we're doing is using the fact that each side is a quadratic polynomial in $x$, since they are equal, the coefficients have to be the same.  Equal polynomials have equal coefficients! Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Consider $z^2+z-2=(z+2)(z-1)=-2(1+\frac{1}{2}z)(1-z)$. Its inverse (as a formal power series) is
$$
-\frac{1}{2}(1+z+z^2+\dotsb)\left(1-\frac{1}{2}z+\frac{1}{4}z^2+\dotsb\right)
=-\dfrac{1}{2}-\dfrac{1}{4}z-\dfrac{3}{8}z^2+\dotsb
$$
Interpret $z$ as the differentiation operator and “multiply” by $x^2$ (that's why we can discard higher order terms):
$$
-\dfrac{1}{2}x^2-\dfrac{1}{4}2x-\dfrac{3}{8}2=-\dfrac{1}{2}x^2-\dfrac{1}{2}x-\dfrac{3}{4}
$$